# Is there a distinction between the "squared semi-partial correlation" and the "semi-partial R squared" of a fixed predictor?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, r-squared, effect-size

The package ['r2glmm'](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/r2glmm/versions/0.1.1) in R calculated the "semi-partial R squared" of each fixed predictor in a mixed effects model. The package describes this as

> "The semi-partial R squared statistic corresponds to a select subset
>   of fixed predictors in a fitted model and measures the relative
>   increase in association between the dependent and independent
>   variables resulting from the inclusion of the specified subset."

I am wondering if this is synonymous with the squared semi-partial correlation for each predictor?

Note that the package calculates the Marginal R squared of the model as a whole. I wonder if it does this for the fixed predictors as well, which would explain the difference.